# How to interleave these two lists into one list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [10, 20, 30]
```

output should be like [[a:10], [b:20], [c:30]]

I do know how to use the zip to interweave two lists

```
l = []
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    l.append([x,y])
```

And the output is :  [['a', 10], ['b', 20], ['c', 30]]
instead of [[a:10], [b:20], [c:30]]

How should I make like this with ':'
Thanks

Comment: The colon means it's a dictionary structure. You need to do: `l.append({x: y})`

Comment: Or are you wanting to print it out differently?

Comment: Try: `l.append(":".join([x,str(y)]))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean to create a list of singleton dicts, you can `zip` the two lists, convert sequence of value pairs to singletons with another `zip`, and map the resulting sequence to the `dict` constructor:

```
list(map(dict, zip(zip(a, b))))
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
[{i: j} for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

Both return:

```
[{'a': 10}, {'b': 20}, {'c': 30}]
```